# Angular JS variable listed before passing as function parameters when constructing controllers,services etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, parameters, controller

I am in the process of learning Angular.js and trying to understand the syntax for passing variables to functions when constructing things like a controller or directive. I've seen the syntax below used when constructing a controller.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.somestuff = "some stuff";  
}]);
```

When the variable `$scope` is placed before it is used in the function.

I've also seen this syntax where `$scope` is just used in the function without having to place it before the function and place both within square brackets.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.somestuff = "some stuff";  
});
```

Can someone explain the difference here and if there is a preferred method? Codecademy uses the 1st method, whereas W3Schools uses the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is called [Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). There are three different methods to make the dependency injection work.

Your first one is the **inline array annotation**. You define the dependencies as a string and angular injects them in the same order to the last element of the array, your function.

Your second syntax is the the **implicit dependency injection**. Angular tries to get the right dependency by the function argument names.

The last possibility to get your dependencies injected is the **$inject property**.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl); 
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyCtrl($scope) {
... // your ctrl code
}
```

$scope gets injected explicitly with the function property.

It is recommended to use the inline array annotation or the $inject property because both ways are not affected by minifying your code. The implicit dependency injection should only be used for small projects or code snippets.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your explanation. makes sense to me now. I would love if these online tutorials actually explained stuff like this instead of just glazing over.

Comment: The documentation if angular is quite good and yeah most of the tutorials are just focused on the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've faced [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

In your two examples the difference is only in the annotation. First example uses inline array annotation (and is the preferred way to annotate application components) and the second one uses implicit annotation. You can read more about them in the link I've left above.

Hope that helped.